# Migration from ant to Maven producing 100+ jars

Tags: maven, maven-2, ant

We are trying to migrate our builds from `ant` to `maven`. Project I am working for is using `ant` since ages. Scripts are real complex where build artifact is a zip file having a definite directory structure. Build creates about 108 unique jars and packages them to this zip file along with many config files and other 3rd party jars.

We need this zip file to be same as now even after migration to Maven. I am just a learner on Maven as of now. My question to you guys is that if there is a way using which I can use one pom.xml to produce more that one jar file, providing list of jars and includes, excludes packages for each.

I googled and found that in case we need multiple jars from one project but different packages, we can do so by placing one pom.xml at each package (jar will be created from this package) and bonding all using dependency management.

But this does not solves my problem, as having 100+ pom.xmls does not seems to be a good idea.

Hope I have made my question clear. Please suggest if there is a way out.

Comment: "We need this zip file to be same as now even after migration to Maven." -> If this is your requirement, then Maven is the wrong tool. It will be more trouble than it's worth to hammer this square peg into a round hole.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Udo's answer here's another [Sonatype blog posting](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/08/how-to-migrate-from-ant-to-maven-project-structure/) with a diagram explaining the Maven anti-pattern of generating multiple jars from a single Maven project.

Both articles recommend adopting a modular structure to your code rather than fighting Maven's approach of decoupling large projects into a set of interrelated sub-modules.

## Incremental publish approach

Start with looking at the arifacts you actually plan to share. Your mail suggests that the only file you're actually publishing is a large zip file containing 100+ jars and other files?

You could invoke the Maven [command-line tool](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) to publish this zip to the Maven repository:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
    -Durl=$REPO_URL \
    -DrepositoryId=$REPO_ID \
    -DgroupId=org.myorg \
    -DartifactId=myproj \
    -Dversion=1.2.3  \
    -Dpackaging=zip \
    -Dfile=myproj.zip
```

This approach can also be used to publish jars and POMs (containing dependencies). Eventually you'll be overwhelmed with the number of POMs to maintain.... AT which time it would be simpler to restructure the building of that jar into a sub-module.

## Alternative to switching build technology

It's very difficult to walk away from a legacy ANT build. These often contain complex, custom and difficult to reproduce build logic. For such projects I recommend using [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to externalise 3rd party dependencies and share artifacts with other projects (who might be using Maven).

To that end I wrote an [ant2ivy](https://github.com/myspotontheweb/ant2ivy) script for generating an initial ivy setup, based on the jars that already exist in the ANT project's directory (normally committed alongside the source).

Using ivy doesn't get you away from the fact that it's a good idea to create project sub-modules. However it does enable you to modernise your ANT build.

### Update

Yes, there are [Maven ANT tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html) available. I don't use them because they based on Maven 2. I'm disappointed that we're still waiting for their Maven 3 replacement [aether-ant-tasks](https://github.com/sonatype/aether-ant-tasks) (Only available from GitHub). Ivy is still the no1 choice for integrating non-Maven clients with a Maven repository

Answer (score 0):

Well you can [generate multiple jars out of one project](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/).

Its not really considered best practice. Look at the supplied article and decide it yourself.

In the includes your are not limited to packages, however this surely makes it easier. :)