# Migrating complex project from Ant to Maven - How to handle unusual folder structures?

Tags: java, maven, ant, build

In my new project I am confronted with a complex infrastructure with several modules which have grown over the years in an unpleasant, uncontrolled way.

To come to the point: The build process is the horror. There are over 40 different, complex Ant files, which are connected multiple times and the SOA framework also generates several dynamic Ant files. It took a few days to really understand all the dependencies and to finally build the whole project without any errors.

My plan was or is to migrate the whole project from Ant to Maven, since new components are planned and I would like to avoid these problems in the future and well, because it is just horrible the way it is now ;-)

Since I am new to the migration of bigger projects, I am a little bit confused about the best workflow. There are dozens of XML files and scripts involved, which are distributed in a non-Maven directory structure. Overall there are over 3000 files involved. One of the main problems is that I don't know if I really should try to migrate everything in the known Maven directory structure and therefore risk endless editing and refactoring of every single file. Or should I keep the folder structure as it is and bloat my pom.xml files and possibly run into problems with all the different involved plugins? Honestly, both ways don't sound quite constructive.

Does it even make sense to migrate a project in this dimension to Maven? Especially when the SOA framework must use its own Ant files - therefore a combination of Ant and Maven would be necessary. What would be the best strategy to simplify this process?

Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: "Does it even make sense to migrate a project in this dimension to Maven?" Depends on what your goal is. In general I would tend to "no", specifically especially because of the horror of "dynamically generated Ant files". I would _never again_ start such a project using Ant - but converting an existing project is a completely different cup of tea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465656/migration-from-ant-to-maven-producing-100-jars/8466366#8466366

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here's a simple and quick answer to Mavenizing an Ant project:

***DON'T DO IT!***

This is not some anti-Maven screed. I use Maven, and I like Maven. It forces developers not to do stupid things. Developers are terrible at writing build scripts. They want to do things this way and not the way everyone else does. Maven makes developers setup their projects in a way that everyone can understand.

The problem is that Ant allows developers to do wild and crazy things that you have to completely redo in Maven. It's more than just the directory structure. Ant allows for multiple build artifacts. Maven only allows for one per `pom.xml`<sup>1</sup>. What if your Ant project produces a half dozen different jar files -- and those jar files contain many of the same classes? You'll have to create a half dozen Maven projects just for the jars, and then another half dozen for the files that are in common between the jars.

I know because I did exactly this. The head of System Architecture decided that Maven is new and good while Ant must be bad and Evil. It didn't matter that the builds worked and were well structured. No, Ant must go, and Maven is the way.

The developers didn't want to do this, so it fell to me, the CM. I spent six months rewriting everything into Maven. We had WSLD, we had Hibernate, we had various frameworks, and somehow, I had to restructure everything to get it to work in Maven. I had to spawn new projects. I had to move directories around. I had to figure out new ways of doing things, all without stopping the developers from doing massive amounts of development.

This was the inner most circle of Hell.

One of the reasons why your Ant projects are so complex probably has to do with dependency management. If you are like our current shop, some developer decided to <strike>hack together</strike> *develop* their own system of dependency management. After seeing this dependency management system, I now know two things developers should never write: Their own build files, and dependency management systems.

Fortunately, there is an already existing dependency management system for Ant called [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy). The nice thing about Ivy is that it works with the current Maven architecture. You can use your site's centralized Maven repository, and Ivy can deploy jars to that repository as Maven artifacts.

I created an Ivy project that automatically setup everything for the developers. It contained  the necessary setup and configuration, and a few macros that could replace a few standard Ant tasks.  I used `svn:externals` to attach this Ivy project to the main project.

Adding the project into the current build system wasn't too difficult:

- I had to add in a few lines in the `build.xml` to integrate our `ivy.dir` project into the current project.
- I had to define an `ivy.xml` file for that project.
- I changed any instance of `<jar` and `</jar>` to `<jar.macro` and `</jar.macro>`. This macro did everything the standard `<jar/>` task did, but it also embedded the `pom.xml` in the jar just like Maven builds do. (Ivy has a task for converting the `ivy.xml` file into a `pom.xml`).
- I Ripped out all the old dependency management crap that the other developer added. This could reduce a `build.xml` file by a hundred lines. I also ripped out all the stuff that did checkouts and commits, or ftp'd or scp'd stuff over. All of this stuff was for their Jenkins build system, but Jenkins can handle this without any help from the build files, thank you.
- Add a few lines to integrate Ivy. The easiest way was to delete the jars in the `lib` directory, and then just download them via `ivy.xml`. All together, it might take a dozen lines of code to be added or changed in the `build.xml` to do this.

I got to the point where I could integrate Ivy into a project in a few hours -- if the build process itself wasn't too messed up. If I had to rewrite the build.xml from scratch, it might take me a two or three days.

Using Ivy cleaned up our Ant build process and allowed us many of the advantages we would have in Maven without having to take a complete restructuring.

By the way, the most helpful tool for this process is [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com). This allowed me to quickly verify that the new build process was compatible with the old.

---

### Moving onto Maven Anyway...

The funny thing is that once you have integrated your Ant projects with Ivy, turning them into Maven projects isn't that difficult:

- Clean up the logic in your `build.xml`. You might have to rewrite it from scratch, but without most of the dependency management garbage, it's not all that difficult.
- Once the `build.xml` is cleaned up, start moving directories around until they match Maven's structure.
- Change source to match the new directory structure. You may have a WAR that contains *css files in a non-standard location, and the code is hardwired to expect these files in that directory. You may have to change your Java code to match the new directory structure.
- Break up Ant projects that build multiple projects into separate Ant projects that each builds a single artifact.
- Add a `pom.xml` and delete the `build.xml`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, I know this isn't entirely true. There are Maven projects with sub-projects and *super poms*. But, you will never have a Maven project that builds four different unrelated jars while this is quite common in Ant.

Comment: I realize this is a very old post, but wanted to understand the scale with which you worked. What would be the approximate number of projects you worked during this 6 month re-write period?

Answer (score 12):

I have done a similar migration in the past, and I had the same doubts you had; however, I went for the "keep the folder structure intact and specify the paths in the POM files" way and I noticed it wasn't as bad as I thought.

What I actually had to do was to appropriately set the `<sourceDirectory>` and the `<outputDirectory>`and maybe add some inclusion and exclusion filters, but in the end I'd say that even if Maven's way is really convention-over-configuration-ish and makes your life easier if you follow its directives on where to place files, it doesn't really make it *much* harder if you don't.

Besides, something that really helped me when migrating was the possibility to divide the Maven project in modules, which I initially used to replicate the Ant structure (i.e. I had one Maven module for each build.xml file) making the first stage of the migration simpler, and then I changed the module aggregation to make it more meaningful and more Maven-like.

Not sure if this does actually make any sense to you, since I didn't have any generated Ant files which I recon may be the biggest issue for you, but I would definitely follow this road again instead of refactoring and moving files everywhere to Mavenize my project structure.